# Microsoft OneNote: setting a global page template

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

1. I am currently using Microsoft Office 2010. In OneNote, I know how to set a default page template for the current `section`.  However, I was wondering if I could set a default page template for the current `notebook`, so that whenever I create a new section, the default page template applies. It is very annoying to set a default page template again and again.
2. As an alternative, I was wondering if there would be any method that I use a page style where the page width is fixed, the page length is automatically expanded, and the screen shows where the letter-size paper would end. I use my tablet notebook and digital pen for writing long memos. If I use an automatically expanded page style and save it as a letter-size PDF file, my hand-written notes are split across pages. If the end of each letter-paper could be shown in an automatically expandable page, I can avoid such splits.

ADDED: I found that Windows Journal would be better for the 2nd purpose, although the software development has been stopped.